# GROUP BY Not Giving Distinct Records

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to save a little C# code by having my SQL query eliminate duplicates (of a field called HouseName). I think I need to use a `GROUP BY` clause since I want the number of duplicates that exist. I'm pulling 9 fields, only one of which is an aggregate. But I'm also wanting to pull the primary key for each row. When I include this in the `GROUP BY` statement I'm no longer getting distinct data for HouseName since the IDs are obviously different. Here's a snippet of what works:

```
SELECT HouseName, COUNT (HouseName) AS numRuns, PrimaryVideoSource, EventType
From...
GROUP BY HouseName, PrimaryVideoSource, EventType
```

This works, although it throws an error if I don't include those last two fields in the Group By. OK, got it, I have to include non-aggregate fields in `GROUP BY`.

But if I want to pull the primary key, here's that statement:

```
SELECT HouseName, COUNT (HouseName) AS numRuns, PrimaryVideoSource, EventType, EventUniqueID
From...
GROUP BY HouseName, PrimaryVideoSource, EventType, EventUniqueID
```

Now I'm getting the primary key, but I'm no longer getting distinct HouseNames. I'm getting duplicates back.

How can I include the primary key without losing the distinct HouseName field I'm getting by using the `GROUP BY` statement?

I could give up on getting the Count (HouseName), though that's handy, and just use a `DISTINCT` statement, but it would be nice to keep the count, and I think I got a different error message when I tried that anyway.

Comment: What would be some sample input and output for this? I'm not sure I 100% understand the expected result.

Comment: count of group by on primary key will be 1 every time

Comment: When you have the same `HouseName` with two different `EventUniqueID`, which `EventUniqueID` do you want to pick? You can't have both and have a unique list

Comment: The idea is I want to get the first instance of HouseID, along with it's PK. Using DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY might have suited this need better. However the more I've though about this I think I'm going to create a GUID for each record within the application and deal with it that way. Thanks for the comments, folks.

Answer (score 0):

*We'll have to see some sample input and output to give a great answer, but as a start, based on my understanding...*

You won't be able to get the hierarchical results I believe you're looking for out of SQL like this.

If you need IDs from each row within each set, you'll probably just want to do that in C#. There may be some bandwidth optimizations, but it's unlikely that those would be worth it.

The trouble stems from SQL's lack of a "list" column type. It's just not what it's meant for. Every cell must contain a scalar value, so returning a collection of primary keys is impossible.

I'm assuming this isn't what you want, but you'd have to wrap the ID in an aggregate function to make this work. If you just want to know the "first" record, you could use `MIN`:

```
SELECT HouseName
    , COUNT (HouseName) AS numRuns
    , PrimaryVideoSource
    , EventType
    , MIN(EventUniqueID) ToKeep
FROM ...
GROUP BY HouseName, PrimaryVideoSource, EventType, EventUniqueID
```

Another option, although not super useful if you're then processing things in C#, is to include all records, but also include a count of how many each set contains.

```
SELECT HouseName
    , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY HouseName, PrimaryVideoSource, EventType) numRuns
    , PrimaryVideoSource
    , EventType
    , EventUniqueID
FROM ...
```